# Probability dice based question involving some knowledge of conditional probability.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

An experiment is conducted where a dice is rolled following the rules given below:

It is rolled only once if the first dice throw turns up to 1, 2 or 3.
It is rolled twice if the first throw turns up 4, 5 or 6.
What is the probability that the sum of all values that turn up in the above experiment is >= 6?

In my opinion, the problem is about reducing the sample space, i.e. considering the cases which are favorable. Once we are able to reduce the sample size, we can get to the final answer.

I have tried doing this question from the conventional approach of directly finding the required sample space. As per me, S = {1, 2, 3,41,42,43,44,45,46,51,52,53,54,55,56,61,62,63,64,65,66}
Concluding from the above sample space, P(sum>=6) = 17/21, but the actual answer is marked as 5/12.
I was thinking of another approach, by doing the question using the multiply method. For the required case, first we have 3/6 probability(i.e. 4,5, or 6) and then I am confused, what should be the next element that should be multiplied.

I am not sure why the answer is marked as 5/12. Is the answer given wrong or I am making some mistake?

Comment: The probability of an event is **not** going to always equal to the number of outcomes in the event divided by the number of outcomes in a sample space.  There are two outcomes to a lottery... you win or you lose.  You do not win the lottery with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.  The outcome labeled $3$ in your sample space occurs with six times higher probability than the outcome labeled $41$.

Comment: Suggestion: Roll a second die even if the first die showed a 1,2, or 3 for fun.  Ignore the result of the second die when determining the sum.  Now you have $36$ equally likely outcomes and can use counting techniques to find the probability.

Comment: But, if I roll the die again if 1,2 or 3 comes up, then I am just increasing the sample space, right

Comment: So what?  That doesn't change the probabilities involved.  Instead, it makes the sample space easier to work with.  Rather than having some lopsided outcomes who occur more often than others, you have outcomes who are all equally likely to occur.

Comment: @JMoravitz I am sorry, I didn't got your first response. Do you mean to say that I should create two different events in some way to calculate the probability

Comment: By including the second die even when it is unnecessary, you have the *thirty six* equally likely outcomes... $\{11,12,13,\dots,64,65,66\}$.  For those outcomes who start with a $1,2$ or $3$ such as $12$, their "*sum*" is just their first number.  For all others, their "*sum*" is actually the sum of their numbers.  Out of these thirtysix equally likely outcomes... all of those who start with a six, all of those who start with a 5, and five of those who start with a $4$ have their sum equal to $6$ or more... giving a probability of $\dfrac{6+6+5}{36}=\dfrac{17}{36}$.

Comment: If it was meant to be asking about sums strictly greater than 6, using the same logic that would give $\dfrac{6+5+4}{36}=\dfrac{15}{36}=\dfrac{5}{12}$... again, allowing us to take advantage of the equiprobable sample space that we were able to craft by including the extra unnecessary roll.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the question. Thanks a lot @JMoravitz

Comment: The idea regarding sample space that you shared is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s break down the problem:

If the first roll is 1, 2, or 3, the dice is rolled only once. The sum of the values can never be greater than or equal to 6. So, the probability in this case is 0.

If the first roll is 4, 5, or 6, the dice is rolled twice. We need to find the probability that the sum of the two rolls is greater than or equal to 6.

For a sum of 6: The possible outcomes are (1,5), (2,4), (3,3), (3,3), (4,2), (5,1) each with a probability of 1/36. So, the total probability is 6/36.

For a sum of 7: The possible outcomes are (1,6), (2,5), (3,4), (4,3), (5,2), (6,1) each with a probability of 1/36. So, the total probability is 6/36.

For a sum of 8: The possible outcomes are (2,6), (3,5), (4,4), (4,4), (5,3), (6,2) each with a probability of 1/36. So, the total probability is 6/36.

For a sum of 9: The possible outcomes are (3,6), (4,5), (5,4), (6,3) each with a probability of 1/36. So, the total probability is 4/36

For a sum of 10: The possible outcomes are (4,6), (5,5), (5,5), (6,4) each with a probability of 1/36. So, the total probability is 4/36

For a sum of 11: The possible outcomes are (5,6), (6,5) each with a probability of 1/36. So, the total probability is 2/36

For a sum of 12: The possible outcome is (6,6), (6,6) each with a probability of 1/36. So, the total probability is 2/36.

So, the total probability for the sum to be greater than or equal to 6 when the dice is rolled twice is (6+6+6+4+4+2+2)/36 = 30/36 = 5/6.

Since the first roll can be 4, 5, or 6 with a probability of 1/2, the overall probability is, (5/6) * (1/2) = 5/12.
This is your answer.